# проблема с удалением кук

Tags: php, cookie, unset

Ситуация такая

есть два сайта (domain.com , a.domain.com), с единой БД и тд.

Если авторизоваться и выйти с главного домена, то куки создаются и удаляются для всех доменов.

Если авторизоваться с a.domain.com, то куки создаются для всех доменом, но, при этом не удаляются, если выйти с главного домена, куки на А остаются :( а выйти с основного, остаются на А.

Как это побороть?

При выходе указываю, что нужно уйти со всех субдоменов, ставя точку перед доменом: .domain.com

```
public static function authorize($user)
{
    if (self::isAuthorize()) {
        return;
    }
    $_SESSION[self::KEY_TOKEN] = $user->token;
    $_SESSION[self::KEY_ID] = $user->id;
    setcookie(self::KEY_TOKEN, $user->token, time() + 3600 * 24 * 365, '/', 'domain.com', self::isHttps(), self::HTTP_ONLY);
    setcookie(self::KEY_ID, $user->id, time() + 3600 * 24 * 365, '/', 'domain.com', self::isHttps(), self::HTTP_ONLY);
}

# выходим с авторизации
public static function exit()
{
    unset($_SESSION[self::KEY_TOKEN]);
    unset($_SESSION[self::KEY_ID]);
    setcookie(self::KEY_TOKEN, null, null, '/', '.domain.com', self::isHttps(), self::HTTP_ONLY);
    setcookie(self::KEY_ID, null, null, '/', '.domain.com', self::isHttps(), self::HTTP_ONLY);

    }
```

Comment: Конечно как вариант, можно на сайте А поставить ссылки на вход и выход, на domain.com и потом перенаправлять обратно на сайт А.

Comment: Попытался воспроизвести с помощью тестового кейса — такое поведение не наблюдается. А какие значения у `self::isHttps()` и `self::HTTP_ONLY`? А если попробовать ставить куки на домен `.domain.com`?

Comment: @Aлександр  `перенаправлять обратно на сайт А` и словить бесконечный редирект - логика будет очень шаткой в таком случае.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему вы  куку ставите на `domain.com`  а снимаете с `.domain.com`? PHP отправляет это в заголовок Set-Cookie как есть, а браузеры могут не понять. Второй момент - попробуйте два последних параметра `self::isHttps(), self::HTTP_ONLY` убрать: для эксперимента(обычно их всегда по умолчанию оставляют).

Ещё один момент - попробуйте убирать куки, проставляя настоящее время в прошлом вместо *null*:

```
setcookie(self::KEY_TOKEN, '', time() - 86400, '/', 'domain.com');//например так
```

Иначе, говорят, не все браузеры поймут что это сброс - опять-же. А так ошибок нет, кука с поддомена, живущая в пространстве основного домена: это нормально, а наоборот: политика безопасности не пропустит.

Comment: "Почему вы куку ставите на domain.com а снимаете с .domain.com?"


Проблема в том, что если ставить куку для .домен.ком, то, при авторизации з А.домен.ком, создаются куки для *.a.domain.com и тогда выход даже с главного домена не удаляются :(



Cклоняюсь к решению, единой форме авторизации, как на многих, по типу mail, gmail, yandex. создаем домен auth.domain.com и туда направляем запросы на вход/выход, создавая и удаляя куки для domain.com.

Comment: " А так ошибок нет, кука с поддомена, живущая в пространстве основного домена: это нормально, а наоборот: политика безопасности не пропустит."

ТОГДА можно авторизоваться с еще одного аккаунта :( кука не перезаписывается и старая не слетает. и это плохо.

Comment: @Aлександр не торопитесь решать сложно простые проблемы. С поддомена можно ставить куки в общее пространство( в домен ): это используют многие, проблем нет. Так ставьте куку в пространство домена - на 'domain.com'. Точка в домене куки вообще спорна, смотрите что на PHP net пишут http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php `Старые браузеры, следующие устаревшему документу » RFC 2109, могут требовать . перед доменом, чтобы включались все поддомены.` .  Если вопрос в авторизации, так лучше юзать сессии, просто поменяйте домен - http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-set-cookie-params.php